# Php to take values with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, custom-fields

I have this code:

```
<?php
$adm['web'] = "www.tuweb.com";
$adm['titulo'] = "Mi título web";
$campos = array('adm[web]','adm[titulo]');
for ($i=0; $i<count($campos); $i++) {
?>
    /* add values in each field in the  value="" */
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $campos[$i]; ?>" value="<?php echo ${$campos[$i]}; >"/>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem i have it´s when generate each field , in the value for each field no works value="" for add the value , only this problem

Comment: Question is not clear , what the aim of adding the known dimension values in to the `$campos` Array ? why not using it directly ?

Answer (score 2):

`${$campos[$i]}` evaluates to `${adm[web]}`. You don't have a variable named "`adm[web]`". You have a variable named "`adm`", which has a key named "`web`". The variable variable interpolation cannot resolve this though.

The solution is to use `$campos = array($adm['web'], $adm['titulo'])` instead of the complicated workaround you're trying.

Answer (score 1):

ONLY IF YOU to name the textfield as the array variable name and it value to be the value then this may be what you want

```
<?php
$adm['web'] = "www.tuweb.com";
$adm['titulo'] = "Mi título web";
$campos = array('adm[web]'=>$adm['web'], 'adm[titulo]'=>$adm['titulo']);
foreach($campos as $key=>$value){
?>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

this will set adm[web] and adm[titulo] textfield names {sounds fishy}

better approach would be to

```
<?php
$adm['web'] = "www.tuweb.com";
$adm['titulo'] = "Mi título web";
$campos = $adm;
foreach($campos as $key=>$value){
?>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

it will set the field names as the array keys i.e. 'web' and 'titulo'

hope this helps your case

Answer (score 0):

Dirty though, but you could do:

```
echo eval('return $'. $campos[$i] . ';');
```

So it would be:

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $campos[$i]; ?>" value="<?php echo eval('return $'. $campos[$i] . ';');?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo eval('return $'.preg_replace('~(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])~',"'$1'",$campos[$i]).';')
?>
```